# How can I know if a field value that represent the primary key of a table is automatically generated when the user insert a new record into the table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am not so into database and I have the following doubt.

I am working on an Oracle database using **Oracle SQL Developer** as "IDE".

Here I can examine a table named **coda_rx** that have some fields. One of this field is named **PK_CODA** (it is the first one) and I think that it represent the primary key of this table. It is not nullabe (and this trait is required to be priary key).

My problem is: how can I check if the value of this field is automatically generated when the user insert a new record into my **coda_rx** table?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm whether the column is the primary key of the table, you could join **USER_CONSTRAINTS** and **USER_CONS_COLUMNS** views.

```
SELECT a.table_name,
  a.constraint_type,
  b.constraint_name,
  b.column_name
FROM user_constraints a,
  user_cons_columns b
WHERE a.owner= b.owner
AND a.table_name = b.table_name
AND a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
AND a.table_name   =UPPER('coda_rx')
AND a.constraint_type='P';
```

Now, there are two ways in which a column could be automatically populated:

- **Identity column** introduced in 12c
- **Trigger** and **sequence**

If it is an identity column, then you could query the **all_tab_identity_cols** view:

```
SELECT table_name,
  column_name,
  generation_type,
  identity_options
FROM user_tab_identity_cols
WHERE table_name = UPPER('coda_rx')
ORDER BY 1,
  2
```

If there is trigger on the table using a sequence to populate the column, you could query the **user_triggers** view:

```
SELECT trigger_name, 
       table_name, 
       column_name 
FROM user_triggers;
```

In **SQL Developer** it is even easier:

1. Open the object browser
2. Click and expand Tables
3. Click and expand the required table
4. Double-click on the **column name**
5. It will open the **table view**.
6. Click on **constraints** and **trigger** tab

For more details about the two features, read:

- [IDENTITY column autoincrement functionality in Oracle 12c](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/)
- [Auto-increment primary key in Pre 12c releases (Identity functionality)](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/)